# Signature is incorrect in Wazirx API

Tags: api

I am trying wazirx api with python and postman but both of them show me the following error

(401, {'code': 2005, 'message': 'Signature is incorrect.'})

from wazirx_sapi_client.rest import Client

from secret import api_key, secret_key
import time

c = Client(api_key=api_key, secret_key=secret_key)

print(c.send("historical_trades",
{"limit": 10, "symbol": "btcinr", "recvWindow": 10000, "timestamp": int(time.time() * 1000)}
))

'''print(c.send('create_order',
{"symbol": "wrxinr", "side": "buy", "type": "limit", "price": 45, "quantity": 2, "recvWindow": 10000,
"timestamp": int(time.time() * 1000)}))'''

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same issue just now. Trying to execute the sample statements from the docs page.

What I found on the wazirz-doc pages regarding code 401 was:

```
{"data":{"code":401,"message":"Invalid request: unauthorized access"},"event":"error","id":0}
```

This is when your auth_key does not have access to a private stream